# Access to ttyUSB* from snap (Ubuntu Core)

Tags: usb, snap, ubuntu-core, serial-port

Our app is running as a snap on a device and needs serial-port access to the *ttyUSB* device.

Running `snap list` shows we have a number of snaps (none of which **I think** has a USB Slot)

```bsh
$ snap list
Name                  Version             Rev   Tracking  Developer  Notes
alsa-utils            1.1.2-5             68    stable    canonical  -
bluez                 5.44-3              129   stable    canonical  -
caracalla             16.04-1.35          49    stable    canonical  gadget
caracalla-kernel      4.4.0-119.143-1     81    stable    canonical  kernel
ccm-wda               3.00.0.39132        14    -         dell-inc   -
classic               16.04               19    edge      canonical  devmode
core                  16-2.32.3           4407  stable    canonical  core
dcc                   3.2.1.283           3     -         dell-inc   -
dcm                   9.2.1.52            7     -         dell-inc   -
microservicebus-node  1.14                19    beta      wmmihaa    -
modem-manager         1.6.12-2            131   stable    canonical  -
network-manager       1.2.2-15            263   stable    canonical  -
ntpcontrol            0.1                 13    edge      ogra       -
snappy-debug          0.31.7-snapd2.28.5  219   stable    canonical  -
snapweb               0.26-11             319   stable    canonical  -
test                  1                   x1    -         -          devmode
tpm2                  1.0-5               42    stable    canonical  -
udisks2               2.6.4-2             100   stable    canonical  -
uefi-fw-tools         1.5.2-0.7.2+git     10    stable    canonical  -
ufw                   0.36pre-16.10       14    stable    canonical  -
wifi-ap               18                  208   stable    canonical  -
wpa-supplicant        2.4.3               41    stable    canonical  -
```

Is there a USB gadget snap out there?

Comment: Try running `snap find tty`.  Using `list` shows you what is installed.

Comment: ```
snap find tty
Name          Version  Developer   Notes  Summary
ttimer        0.0.1    jes         -      plain Timer (a tea-timer for systems w/o java)
miniterm-joc  2        jocave      -      pySerial miniterm in a snap
tio           1.30     lundmar     -      A simple TTY terminal I/O application
linux-cl      v0.1.0   rgrannell1  -      change linux tty's colour scheme
```

Comment: That's all the `tty` applications that are available at this time to snap.

Answer (score 1):

You can gain access to devices by defining slots: try [this article](https://kyrofa.com/posts/ros-production-obtaining-confined-access-to-the-turtlebot-4-5) might be useful.

Other than that you need to install your snap using the `--devmode` flag.